# How to render view generated from dynamic url in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, xmlhttprequest

I have a page with a table consisting of each client in a database. I am trying to make it so that when clicking on a client in the table it will pass only that client's data to the next page.

I attempted to accomplish this by making a dynamic url in my urls.py that looks like:

`path("/client/<int:id>", client_view)`

In views.py the client view uses that parameter to search the database for the client with that id and generates a json response consisting of that client's name, client's photo location etc like so:

```
def client_view(request, ID, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = Client.objects.get(id=ID)
    data = {
        "response": [obj.id, obj.first_name, obj.last_name, obj.id, obj.getImgUrl()]
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

However this url is generated within a script on the initial client table page so I'm confused as how to pass this parameter to the page that will open the dynamic url to render it?

The script on the client table page:

```
<script>
    const clientElement = document.getElementById("client") /*table body*/
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const method = 'GET' //http get method
    const url = "/rosterlist/" /*trailing slash important!!*/
    const responseType = "json"


    xhr.responseType = responseType
    xhr.open(method, url) /* open request with specified method at url */
    xhr.onload = function(){ /*upon loading execute this function */
        const serverResponse = xhr.response
        const clients = serverResponse.response
        var clientsList = "";
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<clients.length;i++){
            console.log(clients[i])
            var client = "<tr class='"+clients[i].ID+"'><td><a href ='/client_view/"+clients[i].ID+"'><img src="+"'"+clients[i].image+"' alt='Man'/><a/></td><td>"+clients[i].lastname+"</td><td>"+clients[i].firstname+"</td><td>"+clients[i].ID+"</td></tr>"
            clientsList+=client;
        }
        clientElement.innerHTML = clientsList /* replace table body */
        console.log(clients)
    }
    xhr.send() /*triggers request */

</script>
```

How do I open the url (the href in the script) using xhr.open() on another page? Or should I be attempting to do this another way?

Comment: I am unsure on how your system works. But as you remark here, `as how to pass this parameter to the page that will open the dynamic url to render it?` Can you not pass the client ids to the page that this script serves in, i.e. the view that calls to generate this initial client table?

Comment: I have an initial page that consists of the client table, which uses the script above. It creates a different link for each client ("client_view/this client's id"). My issue is how do I load this url when it is different for each client? My goal is to have the hyperlink attached to each row load that client's data on another page.

Comment: Do see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out what I was trying to do by using Django sessions. In the view that renders the data I created a session variable that stores the id:

```
def client_view(request, id):
    this_client_id = id
    request.session['this_client_id'] = this_client_id
 return render(request, "pages/client_view.html)
```

the view that generates JsonResponse:

```
def client_data_view(request):
    this_client_id = request.session.get("this_client_id")
    obj = Client.objects.get(id=this_client_id)
    data = {
        "response": [obj.id, obj.first_name, obj.last_name, obj.id, obj.getImgUrl()]
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

So now on the client_view.html page I can just open the url with the jsonResponse in JS using XMLHttpRequest() and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and to the best of my understanding, it seems like you are on the right path.

You mentioned

> My issue is how do I load this URL when it is different for each client? My goal is to have the hyperlink attached to each row load that client's data on another page

You are correct and you've partly achieved by using the `href` tag to set the `url` for a given client. You can set an `href` attribute like so in a script, e.g.

```
<a href="/appname/detail/{{ job.id }}/"> job.name</a>
```

So what you've set here can be set to the following

```
<a href='/client_view/"+clients[i].ID+"'>"Client "+clients[i].ID</a>
```

and when a click is made it will be successfully routed by the defined `URL` conf `path("/client/<int:id>", client_view)` and then in your `views.py` you can simply access the `id` in your function definition

```
def client_view(request, ID, *args, **kwargs):
```

Also note that, I would typically handle these functions in `templates` and not in `Js` scripts but since you are already there this should solve your problem.

Comment: How I have it setup currently I can generate a json response on each click. I want to render that data but how would I access that url when it is not static? For example in the first script I open "/rosterlist/", using xhr.open(), whereas for this script I would have to open "client_view/client_id" where the client id is different each time.

Comment: Your `url` conf is currently not static, `path("/client/<int:id>", client_view)` this allows for a dynamic behaviour where the id can be of any number. If you want to access it in a static way then you would have to use some sort of a form to pass the value as an attribute.

Comment: @MalekeThomas have you found a way?

Comment: I'll see if I can accomplish it using a form, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @MalekeThomas please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign  if it has helped in your problem. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I have a template, where i display three buttons View, Edit, Delete

I want that when a user click on a view button, I grab that user id and pass on link but doing it django way. I don't have xp with xml, but I use ajax calls.

#URLS.PY

```
path('/view/job/<pk>/, view_job, name="obj-detail")
```

#views.py

```
def view_job(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=pk)
    if request.is_ajax():
        data = {'id': obj.id,
                'first_name': obj.first_name,
                'last_name':obj.last_name}
        return JsonResponse(data)
    return PermissionDenied
```

#templates

```
            {% for obj in objects %}

            <tr class="hide-confirm">
              
              
              <td class="text-right">
                <a href="#" class="text-info mr-1 obj-view" title="View"
                  data-url="{% url'obj-view' pk=obj.pk"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
                <a href="" class="text-success mr-1" title="Edit"><i
                    class="far fa-edit"></i></a><a href=""
                  class="confirm-delete font-weight-bolder ml-1" title="Delete"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

```js
    $(".obj-view").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var endpoint = $(this).attr("data-url");
        $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: endpoint,
          success: function (data) {
            $("#obj_details_ajax").html("");
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
              var k = key.replace(/_/g, ' ');
                if (value == null || value == undefined) { } else if 
                  (value.toString().startsWith('/media/')) {
                  $("#obj_details_ajax").append(`<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-5"><p 
                  class="capitalize">${k} : </p></div><div class="col-sm-6 font-weight-bold"><a href='${value}' class="text-info font-weight-bold">Download</a></div></div>`)
          } else {
            $("#obj_details_ajax").append(`<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-5"><p class="capitalize">${k} : </p></div><div class="col-sm-6 font-weight-bold"><p class="transaction_ref_number">${value}</p></div></div>`)
          }
        }
        $("#objDetail").modal('show')
      },
      error: function (error_data) {
        handleAjaxError(error_data.status)
      },
      timeout: 6000,
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- DETAIL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="objDetail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="obj_detail" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-center">obj Details</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="obj_details_ajax">

      </div>

      <div class="button-container m-auto">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit_account_url">Edit</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger comfirm-delete" id="cancel_order">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- // ORDER DETAIL -->
```